# Why the Date zone is automatically changing because of which it gets a day less

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am using a angular UI datetime picker to select date, and when the user submits the form the date at front end is in **GMT** zone but when the object gets passed to web api it gets converted to **ISO** format because of which the date gets a day less i.e if date selected was 24th of sep, in Database it get stored as 23rd of sep.

Is there any solution to this without using any other js like moment.js or dateFormat.js ?

here is what i am using:-

```
'use strict';

module App.Controllers {

export interface IPitch {
        RegionId: number;
        CountryId: number;
        CityId: number;
        GHCId: number;
        DateInvited: Date;
        EstimatedAnnualBillingLocal: number;
        EstimatedUpsideAnnualBillingLocal: number;
        EstimatedAnnualBillingUS: number;
        EstimatedUpsideAnnualBillingUS: number;

    }
export interface IPitch {
        RegionId: number;
        CountryId: number;
        CityId: number;
        GHCId: number;
        DateInvited: Date;
        EstimatedAnnualBillingLocal: number;
        EstimatedUpsideAnnualBillingLocal: number;
        EstimatedAnnualBillingUS: number;
        EstimatedUpsideAnnualBillingUS: number;

    }
export class AddPitchCtrl implements IAddPitchCtrl {
        public static controllerId = 'addPitchCtrl';

        common: App.Shared.ICommon;
        controllerId: string;

        private log: Function;
        title: string;
        inputs: any;
        pitch: IPitch; 

 constructor(common: App.Shared.ICommon, mi: any, pInputs: any, datacontext: App.Services.IDatacontext, m: any, commondata: App.Services.ICommonData) 
{

this.pitch = new Pitch();
}

//this method is called on button click//
private addPitch() {
//when i post the data using this method the property "this.pitch.DateInvited" is **Thu Sep 24 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530** (Indian Standard Time)(i.e. in controller)

//the below method calls the web api which actually stores data in db//
return this.datacontext.addPitch(this.pitch).then(data => {
            toastr.success('Pitch information added successfully.',    'Success');
            this.mi.close("");
        }, errorData => {
                toastr.error('Sorry, Something went wrong', 'Error');
                this.isAddBtnDisable = false;
            });
}
} 
}//Controller Ends here

//web api method//
public Pitch Add(PitchInfo pitchEntity)
    {
// here if i see pitchEntity.DateInvited it shows **"{9/23/2015 6:30:00 PM}"**//
        try
        {
Pitch objPitch = new Pitch();
            objPitch.RegionId = pitchEntity.RegionId;
            objPitch.CountryId = pitchEntity.CountryId;
            objPitch.CityId = pitchEntity.CityId;
            objPitch.GHCId = pitchEntity.GHCId;
            objPitch.TypeId = pitchEntity.TypeId;
            objPitch.SourceId = pitchEntity.SourceId;
            objPitch.LevelId = pitchEntity.LevelId;
            objPitch.StatusId = pitchEntity.StatusId;
            objPitch.DateInvited = pitchEntity.DateInvited; // 9/23/2015 6:30:00 PM
            objPitch.EstimatedAnnualBillingLocal = pitchEntity.EstimatedAnnualBillingLocal;
            objPitch.EstimatedAnnualBillingUS = pitchEntity.EstimatedAnnualBillingUS;
            objPitch.EstimatedUpsideAnnualBillingLocal = pitchEntity.EstimatedUpsideAnnualBillingLocal;
            objPitch.EstimatedUpsideAnnualBillingUS = pitchEntity.EstimatedUpsideAnnualBillingUS;
}
catch (Exception ex)
        {

            log.Error(string.Format("Error: {0}\n Stack Trace:{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: GMT isn't a format (whereas ISO-8601 is). Your question is currently unclear. Please show us what values you have where - what the value is in Javascript, how it's being passed in the request, what your code receives (presumably as a `DateTime`?), how you're saving it in the database, and how you're observing the result. There's a *lot* of information missing here.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by creating a new date object and then passing it to the web api.

say the date i select using the angular date time picker is bind to a model "vm.DateInvited" so in controller i am doing like

```
this.DateInvited=new Date(Date.UTC(this.DateInvited.getFullYear(),this.DateInvited.getMonth(),this.DateInvited.getDate()));
```

this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this by using [Datetime.UtcNow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow(v=vs.110).aspx) Property. You dont have to make any changes in the client side (i.e. angular/ jquery) But only in the server side code.